# Invalid read of size 8 and Address 0x59ffbe8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd

Tags: c++, memory

So I get these errors, and I looked everywhere in the net, tried changing lots of stuff but still stuck...

I have a LinkedList with ListNode and the ListNode has a pointer to an object named Candidate.
Candidate has a member which is a pointer to an instance of the object Institute.

When my main ends, then destructor for the linked list is being called, and in the destructor i delete all the nodes.
Since delete first calls the destructor of the node, in the Node class in the destructor i do this:

```
class MyLinkedListNode
{
public:
    Candidate *nodeCand;
    MyLinkedListNode *next;
    MyLinkedListNode *prev;
    ~MyLinkedListNode()
    {
        delete this -> nodeCand;
    }

};
```

and in Candidate destructor i do this:

```
Candidate::~Candidate()
{
    delete this -> school ;
}
```

when school is of type Institute*. (Every new candidate has a new institute)

and:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    MyLinkedListNode *curr = this -> _head;
    MyLinkedListNode *temp = NULL;
    while(curr != NULL)
    {
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr -> next;
        remove( temp -> nodeCand );
    }
}
```

and in Institute destructor I do nothing.

Really, I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Where are your constructors? Also, you don't need `this->`.

Comment: You're violating the Rule Of Three, most likely.

Comment: I dont know the rule of three.. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I would suggest that several Candidates share the same `school` (the pointers point to the same object), so you're trying to delete a single `Institute` object several times.

Comment: @Daniella: When you hear a term you don't recognise, _look it up_.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three

Comment: Inspired, every time i create a new Candidate i also create a new Institute...

Comment: How do you delete all the list nodes? In the list's destructor, do you read `next` AFTER you delete a node?

Comment: After reading the rule of three, I still dont understand what does this have to do with my problem

Comment: You need a copy constructor and assignment operator probably. That's how the rule of three (or five) relate to your problem.

Comment: @Daniella -- Let's go a different route.  Does your LinkedList class have a method that deletes a single node?  If so, then your destructor should be simple -- just call that "delete a single node" function until the list is empty.

Comment: That is what i am doing... remove() removes a node and i'm itterating over the list until the node is null.

Comment: @Daniella - No.  I asked if you already have a function that deletes a single node.  If so, and it already works, why are you reinventing your own wheel in the destructor?  Just call that working routine in your destructor "n" times.  The node you would delete would be the head node each time the loop iterates.  If you have a remove() function, it should be taking a parameter, and that would be the node to delete.

Comment: Sorry, i think thats what i'm doing...

Comment: @Daniella - yes, that is what you're doing, but you're doing too much if you have also implemented an "is_empty" function to determine if the list is empty.  If so, then that destructor can be written in two lines, and without any traversing of the list.  You should post the class interface to your LinkedList class, so that we can see what functions are available.